# How to filter database table using link <a href=''> in django?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

**I try to show a page with posts from that category when the user clicks on a link to a certain category**

**This is mine urls.py file:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostHomeView,PostDetail,NavFooter,PostPageView

urlpatterns = [
 path('navbar', NavFooter, name='Nav_Footer'),
 path('', PostHomeView.as_view(), name ='home'),
 path('PostDetail/<int:pk>', PostDetail.as_view(), name ='post_detail'),
 path('PostPage/', PostPageView, name ='post_page'),
 ]
```

**This is mine view.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from .models import Post, TaskCategory

  def NavFooter(request):
     return render(request,"nav_footer.html", {})


 class PostHomeView(ListView):
     model = Post
     context_object_name = 'post'
     template_name = 'home.html'

     def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.order_by('task_title')[:9]


 def PostPageView(reguest):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    category = TaskCategory.objects.all()

    return render(reguest,'post_page.html',{'posts':posts,'category':category})



 class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

**This is models.py file:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class TaskCategory(models.Model):
   category_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.category_title

class Post(models.Model):
   task_category = models.ForeignKey(TaskCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   recommended_tools = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   budget = models.CharField(max_length=250)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.task_title + ' | ' + self.task_discription + ' | ' + str(self.task_category) + ' | 
              ' + self.recommended_tools + ' | ' + self.budget
```

**The fastest way to access this file via html**

Comment: with the help of a category fild

Answer (score 0):

first add another url route for `category_detail`

```py
path('CategoryDetail/<int:pk>', CategoryDetail.as_view(), name ='category_detail'),
```

Next, add a view for this route

```py
class CategoryDetail(DetailView):
    model = TaskCategory
    template_name = 'category_detail.html'
```

In the `category_detail.html` you can use something like this to display the posts:

```
<ul>
    {% for post in object.post_set.all %}
        <li>{{ post.id }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```